# Using explorer.exe with wildcards in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-explorer

My problem is starting `explorer.exe` with select parameters in batch file. I use this:

```
if exist "!SATIR!\!SATIR:~20,-23!.mp4" (explorer.exe /select, "!SATIR!\!SATIR:~20,-23!.mp4") else (explorer.exe /select, "!SATIR!\!SATIR:~20,-23!.mkv")
```

It works but I don't want to depend on specific file extensions. I want to use something like wildcard for all extensions (avi, wmv, etc.).

Using something like:`if exist "!SATIR!\!SATIR:~20,-23!.*" explorer.exe /select, "!SATIR!\!SATIR:~20,-23!.*"` doesn't work. Fails at `explorer.exe` part. So far I got nothing. Is it possible to do?

**PS.** `!SATIR!` variable contains local address of those mp4 and mkv files. It is something like: `F:\Movies\000y.001y\The.Lord.of.the.Rings.The.Return.of.the.King.(2003){0167260}[00087]`

**PS.** `!SATIR:~20,-23! EQU The.Lord.of.the.Rings.The.Return.of.the.King`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Explorer does not support wildcards for option `/select` as this option requires the path of a directory, or the name of a file (with or without path depending on usage of `root`, or the name of an object. See the command line option pages for Windows Explorer for [Windows 95/98/Me/NT4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510), [Windows 2000/NT4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457), [Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853) (and later Windows versions). Selecting multiple files is not possible with this command line option as far as I know.

But the batch file can nevertheless work with a wildcard for the file extension on testing for existence and then start Windows Explorer with the full name of the file matching first the file specification.

Here is an example batch file:

```
@echo off
set SATIR=F:\Movies\000y.001y\The.Lord.of.the.Rings.The.Return.of.the.King.(2003){0167260}[00087]
set FILESPEC=%SATIR:~20,-23%.*
if exist "%SATIR%\%FILESPEC%" (
    for %%f in ("%SATIR%\%FILESPEC%") do (
        %windir%\explorer.exe /select,"%%f"
        goto :LoopExit
    )
)
:LoopExit
set FILESPEC=
set SATIR=
```

Well, the `if` condition is more or less useless here. The behavior is the same on the batch file below.

```
@echo off
set SATIR=F:\Movies\000y.001y\The.Lord.of.the.Rings.The.Return.of.the.King.(2003){0167260}[00087]
set FILESPEC=%SATIR:~20,-23%.*
for %%f in ("%SATIR%\%FILESPEC%") do (
    %windir%\explorer.exe /select,"%%f"
    goto :LoopExit
)
:LoopExit
set FILESPEC=
set SATIR=
```